# dovecot master user -> how to get information in the sql query to what account master is trying to log in?

Tags: dovecot

I'm looking for a way to have multiple email accounts to which other users can log in using their logins and passwords in the same way as master user.

by adding additional table in my system I could control the access.

The problem is that dovecot can send to the sql query only domain or master user name, but not complete login ( account_name*master_user_login) or separately the account name. 
Is there an undocumented shortcut like with the '%; that provides that info ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Dovecot documentation](http://wiki.dovecot.org/Authentication/MasterUsers),

> `pass=yes` is especially useful with a [Checkpassword](http://wiki.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase/CheckPassword) passdb because the script gets both the login and the master username as environment variables. Other passdbs see only the login username in `%u`. In the future there will probably be another setting to make the user verification to be done from userdb.

(1.x and 2.x documentation say the same thing.)

Conclusion: if you are using Checkpassword for your passdb then you are good. Otherwise, this clearly states that the passdb doesn't get access to the master username, so the answer to your question is no.

If you want to know about undocumented shortcuts, then UTSL. But I doubt there is one.